# Making sure my RNG doesn't crash based on a user input String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I made a random number generator and if anyone uses this without numbers it will crash
How do I make sure if user input is a String it won't crash, but rather say "Invalid argument"?

```
static int random; 
static String string;
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String args[])  {


    System.out.println(getRandomNum());
    int guessResult =1;
    int randomGuess= 0;
    while(guessResult != -123) {

        System.out.print("Guess a number between 0 and 50");

        randomGuess = scanner.nextInt();
        guessResult = checkGuess(randomGuess);

    }

    System.out.println("Yes the random number is " + randomGuess);

}

public static int getRandomNum() {


    random = (int)(Math.random() * 51);
    return random;
}

public static int checkGuess(int guess) {

    if(guess == random) {

        return -123;

    }else {
        System.out.println("please retry " +guess + " was not correct");
        return guess;


    }

}
```

}

Comment: Use a try statement or do a check.

Comment: 3 search terms: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+exception+handling , welcome

Comment: ..and in particular: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt-- ..esp. the "Throws:" section.

Comment: Where would I try and catch the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your input scan into a `try-catch` block:

```
try{
  randomGuess = scanner.nextInt();
  guessResult = checkGuess(randomGuess);
}
catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.println("Invalid argument");
}
```